# /var/run directory creation even though service is disabled

Tags: linux, systemd, debian-jessie

Usually, directories to store pid's or similar are created by the startup scripts of the services. (See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/306479/75864))

However, I just noticed that these directories are still re-created after a reboot when I disable the services. This happened for all the services I tried.

```
root@sonorus:~# systemctl status openvpn
● openvpn.service - OpenVPN service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
root@sonorus:~# systemctl status ejabberd
● ejabberd.service - A distributed, fault-tolerant Jabber/XMPP server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ejabberd.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/docs/
```

Which service is actually creating these directories?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With systemd, there is a new functionality called `tmpfiles.d(5)` that can be used to create files or directories on boot outside of the .service file. Openvpn and ejabberd are both using this, so that's why the directories in `/var/run` are still created even if they are not started on boot.

The `tmpfiles` configuration files are stored in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/`

Comment: I could, for the sake of it, not find out what was creating these directories, but this is the solution. Thanks so much!